# Python Pandas: How to get column values to be a list?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with one column and 20 rows. I want to use

```
dataframe[column].apply(lambda x : some_func(x))
```

to get second column. The function returns a list. Pandas is not giving me what I want. It is filling the second column with NaN instead of the list items that some_func() is returning.

Is there a clever or simple way to fix this?

Comment: You're definitely going to need more info here, a simple example has this working for me (a function which returns a list applies fine on a column), can you provide the/an example where it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error was cause because I forgot to include:
    axis = 1

My full line of code should have been:

```
dataframe[column].apply(lambda x : some_func(x), axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign it like a dictionary:

```
dataframe['column2'] = dataframe['column1'].apply(lambda x : some_func(x))
```

Simple as that.